# Bash - extract substring in a string with special characters

Tags: bash, substring

I'm trying to extract `43` (downloader/request_count result) in the string below:

```
OUT="[scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats: {'downloader/request_bytes': 21394, 'downloader/request_count': 43, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 43, 'downloader/response_bytes': 1030981, 'downloader/response_count': 43, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 43, 'item_scraped_count': 41"
```

In a first step, I did `value=${OUT#*request_count\':}`, which return:

```
43, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 43, 'downloader/response_bytes': 1030981, 'downloader/response_count': 43, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 43, 'item_scraped_count': 41
```

But when I try to delete right part, I get an error:

```
value2=${value%,*}
```

or

```
value2=$(cut -d, -f1 $value)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` removes the shortest possible string, use `%%` to remove the longest possible one:

```
value2=${value%%,*}
#             ~~
```

Also, you might want to remove the space after the colon, too:

```
value=${OUT#*request_count\': }
#                            ~
```